# How can I allow USB debugging to an specific computer?

Tags: usb-debugging

First of all, forgive my english please. I hope somebody can undestand this.

I have a broken touchscreen, so I'm controlling the device with a mouse via microUSB. Now I've tried different mirror clients (Airdroid, Mobizen and ApowerMirror) and they work just until I try to control the smartphone, then all of them asks to allow the computer USB debugging, the problem is that, I can't allow from the smartphone with the mouse because I have to connect the USB cable.

The screen that ask to allow debugging shows some digits with a message like "The digital print of your RSA password is:"

Sony Xperia Z1 Compact, Macbook Pro